# A formula to calculate summation of nCr with r ranging from a to b(b>a)

Tags: summation, combinations

I want to find a simple formula for this

$$\sum_{r=a}^b nCr  =  ?$$

for example 
$$\sum_{i=0}^n i^2 = \frac{(n^2+n)(2n+1)}{6}$$
Here a and b are natural numbers and r is being incremented by 2 after every step. so if (a,b) = (1,7) then r will have values 1,3,5 and 7. n will also be a natural number which will be a constant.

I searched the net but i could only find it for r ranging from 0 to n.

Comment: I think there is no a closed form

Comment: sorry i didnt get you. what do you mean ?

Comment: I mean that there is no any expression can represent this for any a,b,n,r

Comment: Oh is that so. Thanx for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula ncr of combinatorics can be expressed in summation form or as a series by using MULTIPLE SIGMA notation. Look up the link I have posted here and you will find a paper titled-"THE FORMULA nCr REVISITED" by Soumendra Nath Banerjee.
The proof of the formula is also given in the paper itself.

The formula is as below-------
[How the formula looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9re8C.png)

Open the link below and scroll down till you find the paper titled "THE FORMULA nCr REVISITED"

[THE FORMULA nCr REVISITED](https://jmscm.smartsociety.org/vol1_no1.html)

I am also giving the abstract below.

I hope this answers your question. Thank you for your patient reading.

Abstract-
A formula expressing n C r in summation form is formulated by the use of algorithmic counting techniques. Initially, a general counting problem is mathematically modeled and its solution is given by a formula derived using algorithmic counting. Thus, by generalization a formula for nCr as a series is obtained.
Keywords: n C r, summation, algorithm, counting, mathematical modeling, generalization, series.

Comment: Hello, what your paper states is a generalized formula for nCr as a series. But what I am asking for is a formula for the summation of nCr with r ranging from a to b. But after seeing that formula, I think we can write the formula as a summation of all the sigmas for different nCr with r ranging from a to b.

Comment: Yes you are right. We can write that generalized formula as a summation of all sigmas for a particular value of n. And then vary r.